# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' With office 2016 vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, runtime-error, oledb

1. I made a data program with vb.net 2010
2. it works fine on most pcs
3. it doesnt run on a pc have a office 2016
4. It make the famous error in title ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine)
5. The big problem is the  user pc with office 2016 doesnt have adminstor permissions to install anything

What can i do??

Comment: Is that machine running 64-bit Windows? Is the target platform for your project Any CPU?

Comment: Please See this First. [How-do-I-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you @jmcilhinney
yes the machine is 64-bit
and the target platform is X86
i changed it to anycpu and the error become on my machine

Comment: Any help from anyone can answer this question